# Azure: Unable to start the sandbox on Azure Training

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am doing the Azure fundamentals course and require the sandbox environment to do the course.
But despite refreshing the page a hundred times( following the instruction from the troubleshooting page ) I see the same error.

`Email is required to activate a sandbox

Your Microsoft account must be linked to a valid email to activate a sandbox. Go to Microsoft Account Settings to link your email and try again.`

Not sure why I am seeing this error as I am already logged in.

Any ideas that might help?

Answer (score 18):

In my case the email address was verified, yet I still had the same issue.

Here is what I do to make Azure Sandbox work:

- Log out from https://learn.microsoft.com
- Log out from https://account.microsoft.com
- Log in using **email address** on https://learn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 5):

in my case, long ago, I created the account with an alias when I signed up for skype. Recently I added the @outlook.com email.

I fixed the issue by login using the email @outlook instead of my skype login.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. This was working for me a few months back. Also my account alias seems to be verified since there is no "Verify" button against it on the "Manage how you sign in" page.

I had created the Microsoft account with a username and email id(alias) logging in with the email id solved this issue. This check for email id must have been added recently, because I'd run the sandbox with my username login multiple times in the past.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't verified your email address linked to your MSA.

When you sign up for a Microsoft account or add an email address to your account,  a request will be sent to that email for you to verify. To finish the process, just follow the verification link in the email. If you need a new verification email:

- Sign in to Manage how you sign in to Microsoft.
- A **Verify** button will be next to any unverified aliases.
- Click **Verify** next to your email address, and then click **Send email**.

See details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026276/microsoft-account-how-to-verify-an-email-address).

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. In my case, I had created the Azure account by using my phone number instead, and subsequently added an email as alias (which was verified), yet I still had the problem. Regardless, following these steps in order allowed me to then have access to the sandbox

Answer (score 1):

It used to work for me too, until it didn't.

This helped: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/7694/sandbox-activation-failing-1.html

Essentially, what worked for me was to go to the Profile (click the icon at the top right of the page and click "Profile"), under "Settings", add my email address to the "Email for notifications" field.

Then make sure to log out and then back in and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Profile
2. Click Settings
3. locate "Manage your email preferences", enter your email address and press save.

Retry and it should work. At least it did for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when working on some Azure training courses.

When I try to activate the sandbox, I get the error:

```
Email is required to activate a sandbox or lab

Your Microsoft account must be linked to a valid email to activate a sandbox or lab. Go to Microsoft Account Settings to link your email and try again.

For more information, please check the troubleshooting guidance page.
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The problem was that I was logging in with my username instead of my full email.

So instead of `my-username@outlook.com`, I was using the username `my-username`.

All I had to do was to log out from https://learn.microsoft.com and https://account.microsoft.com

Afterwhich, I logged in to https://learn.microsoft.com/ with my email which is  `my-username@outlook.com`

This time everything worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Just **Sign out** yourself, and **Sign in** using your email address. it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have linked your outlook email.
If its already linked then log out from MS Learn and try login again.
Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.
I had added an outlook.com email alias to my account and set it as the primary.
No matter how I logged in, be it the new outlook.com address or my original hotmail.com address, I would get that error.

Setting my original hotmail.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33915859)